# Codeigniter HMVC modules locations

Tags: codeigniter, module, hmvc, hmvc-codeigniter

In my codeigniter application I'm using codeigniter HMVC.
And it works fantastic!

But I want to have 2 modules folders:

- one in the `application/controllers/` folder
- and one in the `applications/` folder.

I can't figure out how I need to change the `modules_location` array so this will work.
At this moment my `modules_location` looks like this :

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);
```

I just need to add one line to make this system working, but which one?

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing it this way :

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/core/' => '../modules/core/',
    APPPATH.'modules/plugins/' => '../modules/plugins/',
);
```

and it's working as expected.

I have tried to externalize the modules root outside of the application folder but no success so far, I'll keep testing and let you know if it works and if I don't forget to post it here.

Cheers !

Comment: I also canot externalize the modules root outside of the application folder, did you have any luck with this? Thanks

Comment: Use FCPATH instead of APPPATH constant.